How fast can you detect if two rows in an n by n binary matrix have (at least) two bits in a common position?
Assume we have an n by n binary matrix such as:
[[0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]]

You can determine if there are two rows that have at least two 1s in common positions (columns) in O(n^3) time easily.  In the example above, there is no such pair of rows. In the example below there are:
[[1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0]]

Can this be solved in O(n^2) time or any time faster than O(n^3)?

@Progman There was a typo. The title was correct but I had not transferred "at least two" into the main text.

Why aren't row 4 and row 5 in the first example have two 1s in common positions? I count two 1s in the row 4 and row 5 in column 2.

@Progman Two different columns.

Yes, you can do this in O(n2) time.
Initialize an n x n scratch matrix with all zeros.
Then, for each row, iterate though each pair of 1s at positions (i,j) and check each position (i,j) in the matrix.  If it contains 0, then write the row number (1-n) at that position. Otherwise stop, because you've found a matching pair of 1s between the current row and the row number stored at (i,j).
Obviously, this algorithm can require O(n2) time for a single row, but there are only n2 positions to be filled in the scratch matrix, so the total running time is limited to O(n2) as well.
NOTE: You need to be able to process sparse rows in O(n) time, so start each row by making a list of all its 1 positions.

Given two unsigned integer values, you can determine if more than one bit is set with a simple calculation. That is:
bool singleBit = x>0 && (x&(x-1))==0

If you convert each row to an unsigned integer, then you can do a logical AND for each pair, and check the result with a slightly modified version of the above.
For example:
unsigned r1 = ConvertToBinary(m[1])
unsigned r2 = ConvertToBinary(m[2])
unsigned common = r1 & r2;
if (common > 0 && (common & (common - 1)) != 0)
{
    // more than one bit is set
}

Complexity

Creating integer representations of the rows will require O(n2) time.
Comparing the rows will take O(n2) time.

This doesn't sound like the best possible algorithm unless your matrix is already represented by "rows" of integer values. But it does demonstrate that the operation can be done in O(n2) time.

What do you mean by converting an entire row to a binary value? Do you mean convert it into an integer?

@Simd Yes, create an integer representation of the row. For example if the row has 8 columns, each of which is either 1 or 0, then that row can be represented by a byte.

This method doesn't work if you have more columns than bits in an integer.

I suspect this method would work well in practice but I don't think it is formally O(n^2) time

@Simd Please explain why you think it's not O(n^2).

@MarkRansom It's easy enough extend to work with more columns. Working with multiple integers per row should still be O(n^2).

If you have n bits in a row then each row will be converted into O(n) integers. Your algorithm will then take O(n^3) time to run.  You are assuming that n is less than the number of bits in an integer but then the whole thing is O(1) time anyway if n doesn’t go to infinity.

@Simd It will take O(n^2) time to create an integer representation of all the rows. Then it will take O(n^2) time to determine if there is a row that meets the criteria. That's  O(2*n^2). And because we ignore the constant factors, O(n^2). Sure, it'd be O(n^3) if you do the row conversion multiple times, but that's just silly.

The point is that you will have O(n) integers per row. It is a practical speed up but it doesn't help the asymptotics.
